# Error telling me that the method in my run class is undefined even though it is

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I was trying to get into the Java robot class so I thought I would at first just simply write a program to move the mouse to 0,0 on the screen.

It all looks perfect but when I try to run it I get an error:

```
"The method go() is undefined for the type run"
```

Wondering if any of you know why I was getting this error.

main.java:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run run = new run();

        run.go();
    }
}
```

run.java:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
public class run {

    public void go(){

        Robot robot = null;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        robot.mouseMove(0, 0);
    }


}
```

-Thanks

Comment: Have you tried renaming your ```run``` class to 'Run' (with a capital R). Maybe Java does like the ```run run = new run()``` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of your class is `run`, and that is what the compiler is attempting to use (the `class` *named* `run`) and there is no `static void go`. Basically, you have **shadowed** `run` (I note it is not in a package, and class names *should* start with a capital letter). I suggest you fix those things, but you ***could*** change

```
run run = new run();
run.go();
```

to

```
new run().go();
```

As for the *shadow*, the variable named `run` is ***shadowed*** by the class named `run` (lexically class names are searched before variable names).

```
run runner = new run();
runner.go();
```

would also work.